# Azure vnet and VPN hub and spoke networks

Tags: networking, network-shares, virtual-network

I want my azure vm to connect to multiple client sites simultaneously to access and monitor their servers. I want to avoid unsecure connections I.e unencrypted. Is setting up a vnet the way to go?

I've been reading https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/hub-spoke but wondering if this is overkill for a simple requirement, that's to have my server be able to access multiple client servers simultaneously, I.e have a network connection open to each client.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following file can help https://www.vpnazure.net/en/ - VPN Azure Cloud Service - Build VPN from home to office without firewall permission. 
The best way to manage from 1 server múltiple servers is having just One VPN which means 1 IPSec túnel And encryption. however to reach múltiple clients And servers for management is better to have a dedícated server for it. Additionally if is virtual i recomend to configure a virtual router for additional security. Azure VPN by itself allow secure Connections to almost everywhere however for sepárate purposes has to be sepárate configurated.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion,  I will try it and let you know